# Remove record from Store without causing server call on DS.Store#commit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm developing a push application and need to remove items from a DS.Store without invoking any actions. I'm able to insert objects using load(), but need to be able to "unload" an object after it has been deleted on another client.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than remove a record from the store I just need to change the record state.

```
record.get('stateManager').goToState('deleted.saved');
```

For ember-data V ~1.0 use:

```
record.transitionTo('deleted.saved');
```

Answer (score 14):

```
record.unloadRecord();
```

This clears `belongsTo` and `hasMany` relationships on the record and then transitions the record to the `deleted.saved` state, all without sending anything to the server.

Comment: however, [#unloadRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_unloadRecord) is private

Comment: @SamSelikoff: You are right, so use the unload record from the store object: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord